# How can I use action buttons in a local notification with Cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, ios10

I was using [katzer's `local notification` `plugin`](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications), which was working fine, but it doesn't allow for iOS custom action buttons in the notification. I tried [elizabethrego's fork](https://github.com/elizabethrego/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) because it promises action buttons support, but it depends on `de.appplant.cordova.common.registerusernotificationsettings`, which doesn't exist. I'm currently trying to use [Artfloriani's fork](https://github.com/Artfloriani/LocalNotification), but using the example code doesn't show a notification at all and of the registered callbacks only `schedule` is called.

I just want to show a local notification with two buttons in there, one to pick up a call (e.g. open the app and execute some code) and one to reject a call (e.g. dismiss the notification). Is there any plugin out there that can do this?

Edit:
[Here is the output when trying to install elizabethrego's plugin](http://pastebin.com/U0RRxpEM)